# logger for devenv CruiseControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, devenv

Is there any logger for devenv? I have a devenv task in the cruiseControl.net but it doesn't give me any logs. I cannot even see the reason for build failure. I used to use logger in msbuild to view the log.

```
<msbuild>
......
<logger>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
</msbuild>
```

Is there anything similar for devenv build tasks? Appreciate if somebody can point an example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap devenv.com not .exe to get the log to stdout:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\DEVENV.com&quot; $(BiztalkSLN) /build &quot;Debug|AnyCpu&quot;"/>
```